# show top 5 users on logged user dashboard based on preferences

Tags: php, mysql, relevance

I want to show top 5 users on logged user dashboard based on following criteria:

users are opting following attributes in their profile:

```
Relationship preferences,
Hobbies,
Interests,
Language etc
```

More the preferences will match, highest priority to user's profile will be assigned

table_users

```
userid  ufname  ulname  gender
--------------------------------
1       test1   Test2   M
2       testF   TestF   F
3       testF1  TestF1  F
4       testF2  TestF2  F
5       testF5  TestF2  F
```

table_preferences

```
preference_id   user_preferences
--------------------------------
1               Cooking
2               Gardening
3               Smoking
4               Single
5               widow
6               traveling
```

table_user_preferences

```
userid  user_preference_id
--------------------------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4

2       3
2       4

3       2
3       3
3       6

4       1

5       1
5       2
5       3
5       4
5       6
```

Now, suppose user one is logged in, on his dashboard other registered users (with opposite i.e. gender female) will get display whose highest attributes are matching. As we can see, user five 5 matches most of the attributes so it will be display on top of list and rest will be get display accordingly as follows:

Result required:

```
User_id ufname
5       testF5
3       testF1
2       testF
4       testF2
```

My Query is I am thinking to use relevance search. Will it be suitable. Anyone can help me any suggestions.

Comment: Hello. And whats your problem? Stackoverflow is here to help you with specific programming problems, not to code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide us your code? We can't help you without you providing us your code. We can't know how you coded, so we can't know what errors you did.

Comment: I am not asking for a solution for that. If you have read my message carefully I have asked for suggestions and not solutions.

Comment: `My Query is I am using relevance search and it is not giving me the right results` why you don't simply show us your query?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use MYSQL `JOIN` and `SUBQUERY`

1) Use `subquery` to get the preference of logged in user.

2) Then join table_user_preferences with table_users with `ON tu.userid   =    tup.userid` and `AND tu.gender !=$current_user_gender` and `IN( )` condition to match the prefrence with logged in user preference.

3) Finally group the user and apply order by count of match preference

```
    select tu.*,tup.userid,count(1) as total_match 
    from table_user_preferences as tup 
    join table_users as tu
    ON tu.userid =tup.userid
    where tup.user_preference_id 
    IN (select up.user_preference_id from table_user_preferences as up where up.userid=$current_userid) 
    AND tu.gender !=$current_user_gender
    group by tup.userid order by total_match desc limit 5
```